# Fire an event when an NFC card is presented

Tags: javascript, nfc, google-chrome-app, chromebook, acr122

I am attempting to build a webapp on a Chromebook, I need it to read RFID card serial numbers with an ACR122U NFC. I am using [chrome-nfc](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-nfc).

I am reading cards happily, but I do not know how to fire an event when a card is presented.

Are there any events in chrome-nfc I can use to know when a card has been presented to the reader?

**EDIT:** I have been trying to use chrome.nfc.wait_for_tag, but it does not behave as I would expect.

```
// With a card on the reader
chrome.nfc.wait_for_tag(device, 10000, function(tag_type, tag_id){
  var CSN = new Uint32Array(tag_id)[0];
  console.log ( "CSN: " + CSN );
});

[DEBUG] acr122_set_timeout(round up to 1275 secs)
DEBUG: InListPassiveTarget SENS_REQ(ATQA)=0x4, SEL_RES(SAK)=0x8
DEBUG: tag_id: B6CA9B6B
DEBUG: found Mifare Classic 1K (106k type A)
[DEBUG] nfc.wait_for_passive_target: mifare_classic with ID: B6CA9B6B
CSN: 1805372086



// with no card on the reader
chrome.nfc.wait_for_tag(device, 10000, function(tag_type, tag_id){
  var CSN = new Uint32Array(tag_id)[0];
  console.log ( "CSN: " + CSN );
});

[DEBUG] acr122_set_timeout(round up to 1275 secs)
DEBUG: found 0 target, tg=144
```

Both return the results as above immediately, it does not seem to matter what number I use for a timeout...

If I call the function with no card on the reader, and then immediately put the card on the reader after function call, I get no output in the console.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with chrome-nfc, but taking a shot in the dark by reverse engineering the [source](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-nfc/blob/master/src/nfc.js), it looks like you would want to use the `wait_for_tag` method, like:

```
chrome.nfc.wait_for_tag(device, 3000, function(tag_type, tag_id) {
    // Do your magic here.
});
```

...Where `device` is your reader, `3000` is the maximum time to wait (in ms), and replacing `// Do your magic here.` with your desired logic. If it times out, both `tag_type` and `tag_id` will be `null`.

If you wanted to wait indefinitely, you could just recursively call a function with the above code. Example:

```
function waitAllDay(device) {
    chrome.nfc.wait_for_tag(device, 1000, function(tag_type, tag_id) {
        if(tag_type !== null && tag_id !== null)
        {
            // Do your magic here.
        }
        waitAllDay(device);
    });
}
```

That's assuming you want it to continue waiting even after a tag has been presented. Wrap the `waitAllDay(device);` in an `else` if you want it to stop once a tag is read.

**UPDATE:** It seems the `wait_for_tag` method does not work as intended, so I'm proposing a second solution. I'm leaving the existing solution in place in case the method is fixed by the developers of chrome-nfc.

Another thing to try is to use `chrome.nfc.read`, passing in a `timeout` option, inside a `window.setInterval`.

```
var timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        chrome.nfc.read(device, { timeout: 1000 }, function(type, ndef) {
            if(!!type && !!ndef) {
                // Do your magic here.
                // Uncomment the next line if you want it to stop once found.
                // window.clearInterval(timer);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Be sure and call `window.clearInterval(timer)` whenever you want it to stop watching for tags.

Comment: Thanks @Grinn for your suggestion. I am having problems however, that its not actually doing any waiting, it always returns straight away. I have updated the question with an example of output.

Comment: @Hank what is the value of `tag_id` when there is no card in the reader?

Comment: it is undefined... its as if the function is cancelled and it never makes it to my callback

Comment: @Hank It seems that `wait_for_tag` doesn't call the callback in all execution paths. See my updated and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I tried your second solution and it gave the same result. returned immediately with `DEBUG: found 0 target, tg=144`.

Comment: @Hank do you mean the `window.setInterval` solution that I proposed above? I ask because I briefly posted another solution. With this latest solution you will see that `DEBUG: found 0 target, tg=144` every second or so, as it looks for tags at each interval, but it should find the tag once present.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not consider this a proper solution; here is a workaround I am using for the time being.

```
function listen_for_tag(callback, listen_timeout){

  var poll_delay = 400; //ms
  var listen_loop = null;
  if(!listen_timeout){
    listen_timeout = 99999999;
  }

  function check_for_tag(){
    if(listen_timeout < 0) {
      clearInterval(listen_loop);
      console.log("we didnt find a tag. finished");
    }
    chrome.nfc.wait_for_tag(dev_manager.devs[0].clients[0], 10, function(tag_type, tag_id){
      console.log ( "FOUND A TAG!!" );
      clearInterval(listen_loop);

      // handle the callback (call it now)
      var C = callback;
      if (C) {
        callback = null;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
        C(tag_type, tag_id);
        }, 0);
      }
    });
    listen_timeout -= poll_delay;
  }
    listen_loop = setInterval(check_for_tag, poll_delay);
}
```